# SQL query for self join on a table and list rows that don't match the condition

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have 3 columns (Schedule, Sequence and Occurrence).

The Occurrences for Schedule/Sequence should match and I would like to list the schedules where they don't match.

I would like to print 171344/171466 since the occurrences don't match. 171344 has occurrence of 90/180 for sequence 1/2 and 171466 has has occurrence of 90/180/90 for sequence 1/2/3.

We should not print 171511 as the occurrences of 90/90 for sequence 1/2 match.

There can be multiple sequences and not necessarily 2 or 3.

| Schedule | Sequence | Occurrence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 171344 | 1 | 90 |
| 171344 | 2 | 180 |
| 171466 | 1 | 90 |
| 171466 | 2 | 180 |
| 171466 | 3 | 90 |
| 171511 | 1 | 90 |
| 171511 | 2 | 90 |

Comment: "*We should not print 171511 as the occurrences of 90/90 for sequence 1/2 match.*" - What other sequence matches with occurrences of 90/90 (1/2)? According to the data you have, 171344 has 90/180 (1/2) sequence and 171466 has 90/180/90 (1/2/3) sequence. Is there any issue in your data?

Answer (score 0):

Use `select distinct` to only get the unique values. Then join on the rows with the same Schedule but different Occurrences

```
select distinct t1.Schedule
from foo t1
join foo t2 on t1.Schedule = t2.Schedule
 and t1.Occurrence <> t2.Occurrence
```